# Zend server CE for Solaris

Tags: php, solaris, zend-server-ce

I remember there was a version for Solaris although I only used Zend Server on Windows and Linux only. It seems Zend does not support Solaris, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Solaris is not supported, only Linux and Windows are supported. Actually even some IBM platforms are supported too